Gitlab - report of merges from multiple repos
My team has several repos. Changes in each repo can be pushed to production after merging with main branch for that repo.
I am trying to find out all the merges to main by date across all these repos over the last quarter. Is there a way to do this?
I was able go to "merged" tab for each repo but could not find a way to get a consolidated merge list
